# save a pdf which is displayed by a controllerBase (.Net C#)

Tags: api, pdf, .net-core, controller, system.io.file

This is my method which displays a cshtml as a pdf, that we can download.
I would like to automatically save this pdf before it is rendered by our controller.
I managed to save the file, but I think that there is an encoding problem because when I open the pdf file, I have an error message.

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("Get")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetEmployeeInfo()
        {
            var empObj = new EmployeeInfo
            {
                EmpId="1001",
                EmpName="Arthur",
                Department="Lille",
                Designation="Dev Engineer"
            };
           
           var generatedPdf = await _generatePdf.GetPdf("Views/Employee/EmployeeInfo.cshtml", empObj);
            var test = generatedPdf.ToString();
          
            //reading all characters as byte and storing them to byte[]
            byte[] pdfIntoBtye = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(test);
            //byte[] pdfIntoBtye = Convert.FromBase64String(test);
            MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(pdfIntoBtye);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
       
            string filePath = _environment.WebRootPath + "/PdfFiles/test5.pdf";
            
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
            {
             
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, pdfIntoBtye);
            }
            return generatedPdf;
        }
```

can some one suggest me a solution?

Comment: What is the error message that you get?

Answer (score 0):

i have found a solution (the problem was in my byte[] Properties), now i generate my byte[] directly like this :var generatedPdf2 = await _generatePdf.GetByteArray("Views/Employee/EmployeeInfo.cshtml", empObj);

my final solution : ```   readonly IGeneratePdf _generatePdf;
var generatedPdf2 = await _generatePdf.GetByteArray("Views/Employee/EmployeeInfo.cshtml", empObj);
string filePath = _environment.WebRootPath + "/PdfFiles/test7.pdf";

````
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
        {
         
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, generatedPdf2);
        }
        return await _generatePdf.GetPdf("Views/Employee/EmployeeInfo.cshtml", empObj);```
````

like this, i display in pdf file and save it automaticaly.